# Sorting column with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table that I am using jQuery Datatable for.

```
var myTable = $("#My-Table").DataTable({
    "order": [2, "asc"],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [3] },
        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [2, 3] }
    ]
});
```

Now, the column that I am trying to perform ordering on is a column that contains checkboxes, so on page load I am setting a data attribute for that `td` element and then ordering by that attribute.  The attribute will either be `0` or `1`.

```
@(if item.Active)
{
    <td class="active-td" data-order="0">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
    </td>
}
else
{
    <td class="active-td" data-order="1">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Active)
    </td>
}
```

Now, the user has the ability to deactivate or activate records.. and when they do, I am changing the `data-order` appropriately... but when I call draw, it is not putting the rows that contain unchecked `td` elements at the bottom and rows that contain checked `td` elements at the top like it does on page load.

Here is my jQuery for when a user wants to deactivate.

```
var td = row.children('td.active-td').attr("data-order", 1);  // changing td data attribute accordingly

myTable.cell(myTable.row(row), 2, {order: 'current'})
    .data("<input disabled='disabled' class='check-box' type='checkbox' />")
    .draw();
```

The `.draw()` is not reordering the table like it does on page load.

How do I accomplish this?

Here is what it looks like when I deactive someone:

[image]

I want that row to be ordered so that checked checkboxes be at the top, and the unchecked at the bottom.

**UPDATE**

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/custom-data-source/dom-checkbox.js"></script>

var myTable = $("#My-Table").DataTable({
    "columnDefs":[
    {
        "targets": 2,
        "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox"
    }],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [3] },
        { "bSearchable": false, "aTargets": [2, 3] }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid using `data-` attributes for ordering dynamic data, they are good only for static data.

Use [`dom-checkbox`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/custom-data-source/dom-checkbox) plug-in that allows to sort based on the checked state of checkboxes in a column.

Include appropriate plug-in JS file and use `orderDataType` option for the column containing checkboxes.

For example:

```js
var myTable = $("#My-Table").DataTable({
    // ... skipped ...
    "columnDefs": [
       {
          "targets": 0, 
          "orderDataType": "dom-checkbox"
       }
    ]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/v2yua7wu/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: See my update.  It is not working.  Anything you see that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Checked console and not receiving any errors either.

Comment: @GTown-Coder, added example demonstrating that the solution works. Remove `data-order` attributes which prevent this solution from working.

Comment: I have removed the data-order attributes.  I posted my updated to show you what I have, but still not working.

Comment: I have rewritten your example so that the checkbox column is the 3rd column and it is working like mine. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/troyb12/v2yua7wu/3/)

Comment: @GTown-Coder, when I sort checkboxes in your example, it sorts them correctly. Does it means it works as you wanted it?

Comment: What you have provided helps, but when I deactivate someone, and the checkbox becomes unchecked, the table needs to redraw with that checkbox at the bottom.  This is my problem because the page doesn't refresh because I am using webApi and ajax.

Comment: I'm not worried about sorting when I click the arrows in the `th` element.