# Is there any built-in functionality in JQuery DataTable to pin a row to the top of the table?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need the user to be able to select rows to pin to the top of the table. And these rows should remain pinned to the top even if the user clicks the sort button in the other columns.

I have yet to see anything in DataTable to create this functionality, so is there a better method or JS library to pin a row in the table?

Comment: I think you can get quite close to what you want using checkboxes to indicate "pinned" rows - and then use DataTables `Shift-click` to sort by that column first and then other columns subsequently. See [Sorting column with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47894487/12567365) which includes a runnable demo. That requires the user always sort on the checkbox column first.

Comment: Beyond that, you are probably looking at coding a custom [`$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order`](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/sorting_manual.html) function, if you want something more.

Comment: Thank you so much. The first option worked for me